# How can I input successive different values from a single vector across the same position in multiple arrays arranged in a list in R?

Tags: arrays, r, list, function

I have arranged a large number of arrays into a list and I have a vector which is the same length as the number of arrays with different values. For each array in the list, I would like to input the successive specific values in the vector into the same position in the successive arrays in the list.

For example, if I had 10 arrays of 5x3x10 in a list, and a vector of length 10 with 10 different values, I would like the first value of the vector to go into the first array at position [1,1,1], the second value of the vector to go into the second array at position [1,1,1], the third value of the vector to go into the third array at position [1,1,1], and so on to the tenth value of the vector going into the tenth array at position [1,1,1].

Here is my current code (simplified). 
All the variables/arrays are provide as necessary. 
Currently I have a function that attempts to do this, but the way its written does not allow for the successive values of the variable to be put into the successive arrays. Rather the function tries to put all the values of the variable into the position [1,1,1] of each array, and as such, returns an error.

```
#Starting variables 

dt = 1

person_id <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
clinic_id <- c("c1", "c2", "c3")
time_id <- seq(2008.5, 2017.5, by = dt)

first <- c(13,14,10,8,6,8,7,9,10,12)
second <- c(16,8,9,4,5,6,2,3,4,5)
numbers <- data.frame(first,second)

dims <- list(person = person_id,
             clinic = clinic_id,
             time = time_id)   

#Create 10 arrays 

for (i in 1:10) {

assign(paste("modarrays", i, sep=""), 
     array(NA, lengths(dims), dims) )
}

#Creating array list with 10 arrays

modarraysall <- lapply(ls(pattern="modarrays"),get)
arraynames <- sapply(ls(pattern="modarrays"),as.name)
names(modarraysall) <- arraynames


#Initial values in array 

initval <- function(x){

 x[,,1] <- 0.0
 x <- x

 }

 modarraysallnew <- lapply(modarraysall, initval)


 #Values from vector of dataframe into array 
 #This is where it all goes wrong. 

 numbersintoarray <- function(x){

     x[1,1,1] <- numbers$first
       x <- x

 }

 modarraysallnew <- lapply(modarraysallnew, numbersintoarray)
```

There is no output from this function implementation because I get an error saying

Error in x[1, 1, 1] <- numbers$first : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I think I know what is wrong. This function wants to put the value of numbers$first into position [1,1,1] of each array across the list. However, numbers$first is a length of 10 values where as position [1,1,1] in each array is only one position. Therefore, I know this function is wrong. But how do I write a function that takes each successive value from numbers$first and puts that into each successive array in the list at position [1,1,1].

Below I have shown what I would like the arrays too look like afterwards.

```
modarrays1[,,1] 

        clinic
person      c1     c2        c3 
 a          13     0         0
 b          0      0         0
 c          0      0         0
 d          0      0         0
 e          0      0         0



modarrays1[,,2] 

        clinic
person      c1     c2        c3 
 a          14     0         0
 b          0      0         0
 c          0      0         0
 d          0      0         0
 e          0      0         0



modarrays1[,,3] 

        clinic
person      c1     c2        c3 
 a          10     0         0
 b          0      0         0
 c          0      0         0
 d          0      0         0
 e          0      0         0



....

modarrays10[,,1] 

        clinic
person      c1     c2        c3 
 a          12     0         0
 b          0      0         0
 c          0      0         0
 d          0      0         0
 e          0      0         0
```

I realize I could write this out one array at a time. However, in my actual model code I have 54 arrays in the list so would like to be able to write a function to do this instead.

Comment: `length(modarraysallnew[[1]][1,1,1])` is 1 while `length(numbers$first)` is 10. That's why it can't assign. You'll want to loop over `numbers$first` and `modarraysallnew` in parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform a function element-wise across two different lists or vectors, your best bet is to use `mapply` or `Map`. They need a function that takes as many arguments as lists/vectors you are providing. So in your case, you could try:

```
numbersintoarray <- function(arr, val) {
    arr[1, 1, 1] <- val
    return(arr)
}

m <- Map(numbersintoarray, modarraysallnew, numbers$first)

m$modarrays1[ , , 1]
#       clinic
# person c1 c2 c3
#      a 13  0  0
#      b  0  0  0
#      c  0  0  0
#      d  0  0  0
#      e  0  0  0
```